# Allure Framework Java "Trend" graph. Trying to make it clickable and show previous reports

Tags: java, testing, graph, report, allure

I'm trying to make a clickable "TREND" graph that would provide me a path to previous Allur's reports.
[Example](https://allure-framework.github.io/allure-demo/5/) <- here is working example how that feature should work.
I have found only that [solution](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/issues/644) but it's working (if I understand that right) on Allure-Python.
My question is: does someone got an experience to do that feature but in Allure Java? Or any workarounds to solve that problem?

I've tried to `sed` the javascript code via bash (because I need to run reports in a pipeline in near future), but I'm sure that is definitely not a right direction. Maybe, any other solutions to use JS to generate links for previous reports?